# Wordpress loop "posts_per_page=4" shows only 1 post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a loop where I want to check

1. if there is a custom field checked (checkbox) and
2. if there is content in the loop that follows.

Now I don't understand why the loop always shows only one post:

```
<?php 
//check if field has content
if(get_field("news_kategorie")): ?>

<ul class="page-articles-related">                                                                           
<?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=6&orderby=date&category_name='.implode (',',get_field('news_kategorie'))); ?>
    <?php 
    //check if loop has content
    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="relativ">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </li>  

    <?php else: { ?>
        <?php echo "There is nothing ..."; ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Everything works except `posts_per_page=6`, I see always one post but I want to show six posts.

Comment: because there's no iteration? just an if statement..

Comment: There is no loop that follows. A loop would be made from a "while" or a "foreach" statement which you haven't programmed so far. Your current code can't do anything else but display nothing or a single post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only prints one post, this should print all six posts:

```
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    while ( have_posts() ) 
    {
        ?>
        <li class="relativ">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </li>  

    <?php
    } // end while
```

In your title you said you want 4 posts per page, but in the actual question you want 6, which is it?